# Python module and multiple python-dev installations

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, module

I am developing a Python module and have different Python dev packages, python 2.7, 3.4, etc.
This Python module is compiled from C source.
I have tox set up to test with python2.7 and python3.4.
Like this:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,py34

[testenv]
basepython =
    py27: python2.7
    py34: python3.4
```

Tests in 2.7 are ok but in 3.4 I am getting this error:
undefined symbol: PyInstance_Type
It is also important that C source code is generated by Swig. And the error is comes from a py file generated by Swig too.
This is the code of the python file:

```
from sys import version_info as _swig_python_version_info
if _swig_python_version_info >= (2, 7, 0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        import importlib
        pkg = __name__.rpartition('.')[0]
        mname = '.'.join((pkg, '_mymod')).lstrip('.')
        try:
            return importlib.import_module(mname)
        except ImportError:
            return importlib.import_module('_mymod')
    _mymod = swig_import_helper()
    del swig_import_helper
```

Comment: `setuptools` should automatically pick everything up from whichever Python interpreter you're using to run it. If you do `python3 setup.py install` and `python3` is your 3.4, then it'll use the 3.4 installation; if you do `~/src/python/bin/python setup.py install` and that's a local build of 3.7, then it'll use that installation, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I am installing from tox, which takes care of everything. I have configured tox to use Python 2.7 and 3.4. I am getting this error in 3.4 "undefined symbol: PyInstance_Type". I have also set up travis, but there I get a different error.

Comment: You should edit your question to explain that you're using `tox`—and also how you configured it, and also what you're trying to build. This definitely isn't a `setuptools` problem. It may be a `tox` problem. Or it may just be that you have some C extension module that isn't 3.x-compatible, and is trying to use the C API for old-style classes, in which case the only way to fix it is to port that C code to 3.x yourself. (Unless you're just using an old version of that module, and only need to update to a newer one…)

Answer (score 0):

I get that error when creating the SWIG module using the `Python2.x` libraries and then trying to import it with `Python3`. For example doing something like this (tested in Ubuntu 17):

```
swig -Wall -c++ -python example.i
g++ -std=c++11 -shared -o _example.so -fPIC example_wrap.cxx -L ./lib -lfoo -I ./include  -I/usr/include/python2.7 -Xlinker -rpath ./lib
python3 -c "import example"
```

Will trigger the following `ImportError: _example.so: undefined symbol: PyInstance_Type`

Note the discrepancy between `-I/usr/include/python2.7` and then running it with `Python3`. **Importing from Python2 (or compiling for the desired `python3.x` library) solved it for me**.

Hope this helps!
Andres